# Campo de pesquisa/filtro de dados

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Olá,
Estou a desenvolver um campo de pesquisa de dados.
E este, está a funcionar muito bem até então; mas gostaria de adicionar alguns parâmetros de consulta a este campo.

Como está hoje (possibilidades de pesquisa):

`Data inicial
Data final
Nome.`

Como eu quero:

`Data inicial
Data final
Opção que filtra todos os estoque (abaixo e acima do minimo), outra opção que filtra somente abaixo do estoque minimo e uma ultima opção que filtra somente acima do estoque minimo.
Pesquisar pelo id, nome ou descricao (três colunas diferentes) em um só campo.`

Obs: Existem dois campos para a tabela produtos, relacionados a estoque, sendo estes,  estoque e estoque_min.
Quero fazer uma consulta, utilizando um select, que, dependendo da opção selecionada, traga as consultas caso o estoque seja maior, menor que estoque_min ou todos.

Estou utilizando o método GET para realizar esta consulta:
Segue código da view:

```
<form method="get" action="<?= base_url()?>admin/produtos">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">                               
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label for="dt_inicio">Cadastro inicial</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" name="de" class="form-control pull-right" id="datepicker" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $this->input->get('de'); ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label for="dt_fim">Cadastro final</label>                                  
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                        </div>
                    <input type="text" name="ate" class="form-control pull-right" id="datepicker2" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $this->input->get('ate'); ?>">
                </div>
            </div>                              
        </div>                      
        <div class="form-group">                                
            <label for="estoque" class="control-label">Estoque</label>
                <select name="estoque" class="form-control">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Todos</option>
                    <option value="1">Acima do estoque mínimo</option>
                    <option value="2">Abaixo do estoque mínimo</option>
                </select>
            </div>                          
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="produto">Produto</label>
                <input type="text" id="pesquisar_dados" name="pesquisar_dados" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $this->input->get('pesquisar_dados'); ?>" placeholder="Pesquise nome do produto" autofocus="autofocus">                                
            </div>                      
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer clearfix">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancelar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat pull-left"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Pesquisar</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

Segue código model:

```
    public function pesquisar($pesquisar, $de, $ate){

    if($pesquisar != null){
        //$this->db->or_like('id' ,$pesquisar);
        $this->db->or_like('nome' ,$pesquisar);
    }

    if($de != null){
        $this->db->where('dt_cadastro >=' ,$de);
        $this->db->where('dt_cadastro <=', $ate);
    }
    $this->db->limit(10);
    return $this->db->get('produtos')->result();
}
```

Segue Controller:

```
$de = $this->input->get('de');
$ate = $this->input->get('ate');
$estoque = $this->input->get('estoque');
$pesquisar = $this->input->get('pesquisar_dados');

    if($pesquisar == null && $estoque == null && $de == null && $ate == null)
{ "exibe todos os resultados"}
else
[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]{
     if($de != null){

            $de = explode('/', $de);
            $de = $de[2].'-'.$de[1].'-'.$de[0];

            if($ate != null){
                $ate = explode('/', $ate);
                $ate = $ate[2].'-'.$ate[1].'-'.$ate[0]; 
            }
            else{
                $ate = $de;
            }
        }
        $this->data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->data['produtos'] = $this->Produtos_model->pesquisar($pesquisar, $de, $ate);
}
```

Tabela:
`` id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `nome` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
 `descricao` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
 `preco_compra` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `preco_venda` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `estoque` INT(11) NOT NULL,
 `estoque_min` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `usuario_cadastro` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
 `usuario_alteracao` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
 `dt_cadastro` DATETIME NOT NULL,
 `dt_alteracao` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL, ``

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `estoque` e `estoque_min` são tabelas ou campos da tabela?

Comment: campos da tabela produtos, vou editar a questão, errei...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quanto à segurança, é bom levar em conta o que o desenvolvedor diz: [Escaping Queries](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html?highlight=escaping%20queries#escaping-queries). Assim, recomendo adotar isso aqui:

```
$de = $this->db->escape_str($this->input->get('de'));
$ate = $this->db->escape_str($this->input->get('ate'));
$estoque = $this->db->escape_str($this->input->get('estoque'));
$pesquisar = $this->db->escape_str($this->input->get('pesquisar_dados'));
```

Modo correto de usar [base_url()](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=base_url#base_url):

```
<form method="get" action="<?= base_url('admin/produtos')?>">
```

Quanto ao `model`, apenas use o dado passado pelo `select`, como já está fazendo com os outros campos:

```
public function pesquisar($pesquisar = NULL, $de = NULL, $ate = NULL, $estoque = NULL){
    if($pesquisar != NULL){
        $this->db->or_like('nome' , $pesquisar);
    }
    if($de != NULL){
        $this->db->where('dt_cadastro >=' ,$de);
        $this->db->where('dt_cadastro <=', $ate);
    }
    if($estoque != NULL){
        if($estoque == 1){$where = "estoque > estoque_min";} 
        else {$where = "estoque < estoque_min";}
        $this->db->where($where);
    }
    $this->db->limit(10);
    return $this->db->get('produtos')->result();
}
```

Chamada:

```
$this->data['produtos'] = $this->Produtos_model->pesquisar($pesquisar, $de, $ate, $estoque);
```

Fonte: [Looking for Specific Data (4.Custom string)](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where#looking-for-specific-data)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.
Funcionou para mim a questão do select.

Quando coloquei o base_url como postaste, não funcionou.
Outro ponto, é que, não vi como consultar 3 colunas diferentes num só campo.
id, nome ou descricao (somente no campo de pesquisa).
Isso é possivel?

Comment: Pro `base_url()` falhar deve ter algo errado com a sua configuração. Se esse sistema estiver em produção, recomendo a revisão **urgentemente**. A consulta em vários **campos** numa mesma **condição** deve ser possível com `$this->db->or_like()` (que você já está usando), como descrito [aqui: Looking for Similar Data](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data).

Comment: Verificando sobre `base_url`.
Agora sobre or_like, até funciona, mas aí, a consulta passa a ignorar o parametro data inicio e fim.

Comment: Não procede. A pesquisa por data só é ignorada se você passar um valor `NULL` para `$de`. Lembre-se: para usar `OR`, antes tem que ter um `LIKE`: `$this->db->like('nome', $pesquisar);` e depois `$this->db->or_like('descricao', $pesquisar);`, que vai gerar: // WHERE `nome` LIKE '%pesquisar%' ESCAPE '!' OR  `descricao` LIKE '%pesquisar%' ESCAPE '!'.

Comment: Eu só tenho um produto cadastrado no período de ontem até hoje.
ID do produto é igual a 2.
Veja meu parâmetro de consulta: `Data Incial = 05/01/2017`, `Data Final = 07/01/2017`.
`Estoque = Todos`.
`Pesquisa = 1`
`SELECT * FROM `produtos` WHERE `id` LIKE '%1%' ESCAPE '!' OR `nome` LIKE '%1%' ESCAPE '!' AND `dt_cadastro` >= '2017-01-05' AND `dt_cadastro` <= '2017-01-07' LIMIT 10`

Apareceu na lista de consulta um ID que não deveria aparecer, já que este ID não foi cadastrado na data informada.

Comment: `if($pesquisar != NULL){
$this->db->like('id' ,$pesquisar);
$this->db->or_like('nome' ,$pesquisar);
}`

Comment: Você está, deliberadamente, buscando `id LIKE '%1%' `. Como espera que o programa retorne id = 2? :D

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51312/discussion-between-shutupmagda-and-wagner-filho).